# how to auto adjust of flex box and space a static box in right head

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox

There is a container which is display flex, the width and height of inner flex box is not fixed. I want the box auto adjust to the container and the head and top of the container is fill by a static  box with an certain width and height. there is my code

css

```
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  position: relative;
}
.flex-box {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}
.certain-box {
  width: 80px;
  height: 40px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  background: #fff;
  font-size: 12px;
  box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25) 0px 54px 55px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px -12px 30px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12) 0px 4px 6px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.17) 0px 12px 13px, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09) 0px -3px 5px;
}
```

html

```
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="certain-box">
    The Certain Box
  </div>
</div>
```

js

```
const BASE_WIDTH = 20
const BASE_HEIGHT = 20
const container = document.querySelector('.flex-container')
function initFlexBox(boxCount = 100) {
  function getRandomBox() {
    const boxWidth = randomVal(BASE_WIDTH, BASE_WIDTH * 2, BASE_WIDTH * 3)
    const boxHeight = randomVal(BASE_HEIGHT, BASE_HEIGHT * 2, BASE_HEIGHT * 3)
    const box = document.createElement('div')
    box.classList.add('flex-box')
    box.style.background = randomColor()
    box.style.width = boxWidth + 'px'
    box.style.height = boxHeight + 'px'
    return box
  }

  function randomVal(...vals) {
    return vals[Math.floor(vals.length * Math.random())]
  }

  function rndm(max, min = 0) {
    // [ min, max ]
    return min + Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1))
  }
  function randomColor() {
    // Hue Saturation Lightness
    return `hsl(${rndm(360)},${rndm(100)}%,${rndm(100)}%)`
  }

  return new Array(boxCount).fill('').map(() => getRandomBox())
}

const boxes = initFlexBox()
boxes.forEach((box) => container.appendChild(box))
```

How to style the flex box to empty the place of the static box

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve it by pure CSS, when you position an element in absolute, it goes out from the flexbox layout.

You can take a look to this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d37fxs41/

I tried to achieve it by JS, by appending the "certain box" at the good moment:

```
const boxes = initFlexBox()
let boxesTotalWidth = 0
let firstRowIsCompleted = false
boxes.forEach((box) => {
  const boxWidth = parseInt(box.style.width.replace("px", ""))
  boxesTotalWidth += boxWidth
  if (containerWidth - boxesTotalWidth - certainBoxWidth < 0 && !firstRowIsCompleted) {
    container.appendChild(certainBox)
    firstRowIsCompleted = true
  } else {
    container.appendChild(box)
  }
})
```

Algorithm is not perfect, but it's not so easy since you have random widths.

Notice too that I used:

```
.certain-box {
  // ...
  margin-left: auto;
```

It allows to align the item to the right corner. You can't `align-self` this element.

Comment: I think to find the last box of the first row is a solution, but the static box is not always in the last of the first row in you code

Comment: I find the solution finally. [https://jsfiddle.net/e3uqwfm4/](https://jsfiddle.net/e3uqwfm4/), thanks